# Is there a way to annotate an entire class with @NewSpan? - Spring Boot/Sleuth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry

Is there a way to annotate just the class and have all the methods in the class create new spans? Basically, I am trying to get sleuth/spring to create new spans for all calls in a given repository class.

spring-boot version: '2.7.0'

Something like -

```
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.NewSpan;


@Newspan
public class ContactOperations{

  public void doSomething(){
  }

  public void doSomethingElse(){
  }
.....
}
```

Instead of

```
public class ContactOperations{


  @Newspan
  public void doSomething(){
  }

  @Newspan
  public void doSomethingElse(){
  }
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. The annotation NewSpan is only allowed on methods as you can see in the source code:

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Target(value=METHOD)
public @interface NewSpan
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other annotation that can do this? I couldn't find anything in sleuth package.

Comment: Not as far as I know